# rails Validate has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to validate has_many through association using the id or the validade associated method but, the log spits out!

someone have any idea how to validate a has_many through?
thank's

> syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or
>   tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
>               if !halted && true && (validation_context == :[:update])

```
validates :image_id, :size_id, :color_id,  presence: true, :on => [  :update ]

validates_associated :images, :sizes, :colors, presence: true, :on => [  :update ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :image_id, :size_id, :color_id,      presence: true, on: :update
validates_associated :images, :sizes, :colors, presence: true, on: :update
```

Comment: @jjplack please make sure to accept the answer if that worked :)